# UE4 - UMG button polymorphism

Tags: unreal-4

I want to make a menu with a bunch of buttons. I want them all to look the same and be easier to edit, so I decided to make one "Button Parent" widget, insert it few times and give it a different "on click" action.

I can't access the "on click" event in the main menu widget, also I apparently can't create a button child. My only idea left is to make a public variable for the button, and then do a different action depending on the variable once I set it in the main widget.

Is there a better / easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve it... 
you can use delegates - to delegate the onClickEvent. 
You can pass a pointer to your baseParentWidget and call its functions (interface or whatever).

You can use latent actions (there will be a plugin enabling this for BP soon in marketplace)

Comment: Cool, I will look into delegates.